# Hide JS Library

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a web based application and I got a JS library containing all my JS functions. If I try to open the library via browser I can see the source code. Is there a way to obfuscate it or deny the access to the file to users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, AFAIK there isn't, because the server cannot see whether the browser requests the JS file to execute it or to display its source code to the user. The only thing you can do is to [minify your JS](https://javascript-minifier.com/) file; the browser will still execute it, but for the user it's hard to read it. But it's not hard for anyone to [un-minify / tidy](https://unminify.com/) it.

EDIT: If you have access to the server, you can configure it to compress your JS file before sending it to the browser - The browser decompresses it for execution. I don't know though if the browser will decompress it too, when the file is viewed directly. If he would, it wouldn't make any sense to compress it (except for slightly faster load times).

Answer (score 1):

You can minify and obfuscate but you cannot deny access to the file because the browser will load it along with your webpage.

Comment: Thank you, I'll minify it as @Programmer suggested.